# How to get position of a square div jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
setInterval(function() {
  var divPosition = $('div').position();


  console.log('X: ' + divPosition.left + ", Y: " + divPosition.top");
}, 500);
```

So I can get the `x` and `y` position of this div. `left`/`top` but it's a square div on the page. I'm also tracking a section tag that flies around the page, I want to basically do `if (_thesectiontag_.left == _thesquarediv_.left || _thesectiontag_.top == _thesquarediv_.top) ... do something` so if the `section` tag is within the div coordinates on the page do something.

But I need to get the full dimensions of the square to be able to do that. I'm a bit lost on where to start and how to go about it.

Can anyone offer some help? Thank you!

Comment: offsetHeight, offsetWidth

Comment: Dimensions as in, its position on the page, or the size of it? Or both?

Comment: @DanielT. Yeah so if `my section tag` is over the `div` then do something. So to do that I assume I need the `x` and `y` position of the div and the width and height and i'd need to do some math to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Use this two code :

**For the Width and Height includes padding :**

```
var Height = document.getElementById('square').clientHeight;

var Width = document.getElementById('square').clientWidth;
```

**For the Width and Height includes padding, scrollBar and borders :**

```
var Height = document.getElementById('square').offsetHeight;

var Width = document.getElementById('square').offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div').height($('div').width());
```